# Is there a type for dictionary in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get a request from this link: https://cms.paladins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/champions?slug=dredge&lang_id=1 and transform a class in dart by:
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

But the problem is: the site is generating some strange code that i cant understand:

In inspect of chrome i have:

```
api_information {
Ability1: "Cursed Howitzer"
Ability2: "Broadside"
Ability3: "Harpoon"
Ability4: "Shortcut"
Ability5: "Kraken"
AbilityId1: 23600
AbilityId2: 23611
AbilityId3: 23612
AbilityId4: 23622
AbilityId5: 23613
Ability_1: {,…}
Ability_2: {,…}
Ability_3: {,…}
Ability_4: {,…}
Ability_5: {,…}
....
```

But when i translate to Dart:

```
class ApiInformation {
  String ability1;
  String ability2;
  String ability3;
  String ability4;
  String ability5;
  int abilityId1;
  int abilityId2;
  int abilityId3;
  int abilityId4;
  int abilityId5;
  Ability1 ability1;
  Ability1 ability2;
  Ability1 ability3;
  Ability1 ability4;
  Ability1 ability5;
....
```

I get the int and the string, but why he create a new Class for every dictionary? Is there a type for dictionary in Dart? And why he rename `ability_1` to `ability1` is there a pattern in Dart about underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a limit when using code generators : they don't know the intention behind the json payload and are unable to make the right decisions when facing complex structures.

In other owrds, don't use them !

The equivalent of a Dictionnary in Dart is a `Map`. In your case, probably something like a `Map<String, Ability>` with:

```
class Ability {
  String description;
  int id;
  String summary;
  String uRL;
  String damageType;
  int rechargeSeconds;

  ...
}
```